re.findall with requests doesn't match copied and pasted html (generated by requests.text)
I'm trying to capture some elements from the html code of a certain url.
When I copy and paste the contents of the html directly to into my python code it works well.
import re

# Sample HTML content
html_content = """
<<<HTML Code>>>
"""

# Regex pattern
pattern = r'{"order":\d+,"url":"(https:[^"]+\.webp)"}'

# Find matches
matches = re.findall(pattern, html_content)

# Print matches
for match in matches:
    print(match)

^^ works well. But when I try to do the same by directly using requests.get it doesn't work:
import re
import requests
url = "https://asuracomic.net/series/bloodhounds-regression-instinct-2d0edc16/chapter/59"
response = requests.get(url)
html_content = response.text

# Regex pattern
pattern = r'{"order":\d+,"url":"(https:[^"]+\.webp)"}'

# Find matches
matches = re.findall(pattern, html_content)

# Print matches
for match in matches:
    print(match)

Keeping in mind that the html I'm copying and pasting is actually generated using requests.get:
with open('raw_html.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(html_content)


What is your expected output?

What I'm hoping for is (which is achieved by running with pasted HTML):
output: https://gg.asuracomic.net/storage/media/256676/conversions/01JER36WDKQECK9AY8MEY0B6VM-optimized.webp
https://gg.asuracomic.net/storage/media/256678/conversions/01JER36WEG9MKWWW4FJP3W25CK-optimized.webp
....... etc

I managed to solve the problem by adding:
no_bs = html_content.replace('\\"', '"')

which removes what appears to be back spaces that are not replicated when copying and pasting the html code manually.
Making the final code looks like this:
import re
import requests
url = "https://asuracomic.net/series/bloodhounds-regression-instinct-2d0edc16/chapter/59"
response = requests.get(url)
html_content = response.text
no_bs = html_content.replace('\\"', '"')
# Regex pattern
pattern = r'{"order":\d+,"url":"(https:[^"]+\.webp)"}'

# Find matches
matches = re.findall(pattern, no_bs)

# Print matches
for match in matches:
    print(match)

